# Feature selection based on production data

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, overfitting, lime

**I have a classifer** (one/zero labels) that was trained and hypertuned by the book. When the model was ready, I applied it to the  production data: real-time and unlabeled.

After a short period (a few days); the real-time data became historic data and labeled. **I checked the model real-time data (now, historic data) predictions, and analyzed them using LIME.** If I see that a specific feature many times involves in FP or FN  predicts and I decide to remove it.

**Is it a good strategy or do I create an overfitting situation?**

Comment: +1, nice question and good intuition on "an overfitting situation" as I read it you were thinking of [catastrophic forgetting/inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_interference). See my answer below for more details.